# Application Stop responding when DB Operation and Incoming Call happens at same time

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

My Application hangs when DB operation and Incoming call at same time.. I'm saving huge amount of data into DB. I tried with **AsyncTask** also same result.

Error Logs

```
 08-07 20:04:27.519: I/BluetoothService(1560): <!>android.server.BluetoothService$2 2390<!> Got Call State change - new call state = 1

    08-07 20:04:27.529: E/BluetoothHandsfree(1660):
    <!>com.android.phone.BluetoothHandsfree 3262<!> [BTUI]
    ======================================= 08-07 20:04:27.529: E/BluetoothHandsfree(1660): <!>com.android.phone.BluetoothHandsfree
    3262<!> [BTUI] = RING (INCOMING) 08-07 20:04:27.529:
    E/BluetoothHandsfree(1660): <!>com.android.phone.BluetoothHandsfree
    3262<!> [BTUI] = FORE (IDLE) 08-07 20:04:27.529:
    E/BluetoothHandsfree(1660): <!>com.android.phone.BluetoothHandsfree
    3262<!> [BTUI] = BACK (IDLE) 08-07 20:04:27.529:
    E/BluetoothHandsfree(1660): <!>com.android.phone.BluetoothHandsfree
    3262<!> [BTUI] ======================================= 08-07
    20:04:27.529: E/BluetoothHandsfree(1660):
    <!>com.android.phone.BluetoothHandsfree 3262<!> [BTUI] oCall(0) ->
    nCall(0) 08-07 20:04:27.529: E/BluetoothHandsfree(1660):
    <!>com.android.phone.BluetoothHandsfree 3262<!> [BTUI] oCallsetup(0)
    -> nCallsetup(1) 08-07 20:04:27.529: E/BluetoothHandsfree(1660): <!>com.android.phone.BluetoothHandsfree 3262<!> [BTUI] oCallheld(0)
    -> nCallheld(0) 08-07 20:04:27.529: E/BluetoothHandsfree(1660): <!>com.android.phone.BluetoothHandsfree 3262<!> [BTUI]
    mRingingNumber (+918041113704) 08-07 20:04:27.549:
    E/BluetoothHandsfree(1660): <!>com.android.phone.BluetoothHandsfree
    3262<!> [BTUI] BtUiA2DPSuspend() : mA2dpState( 0 ) : skip...

08-07 20:04:27.579: D/DMClient(1666): <!>com.lge.omadmclient.DmcAgentModeReceiver 17<!> DmcDateChangedReceiver.onReceive()
08-07 20:04:27.589: D/InCallScreen(1660): <!>com.android.phone.InCallScreen 6486<!> Handler: handling message { what=101 when=-1s361ms obj=android.os.AsyncResult@405cdfc0 } while not in foreground
08-07 20:04:27.589: D/InCallScreen(1660): <!>com.android.phone.InCallScreen 6486<!> onPhoneStateChanged()...
08-07 20:04:27.589: D/InCallScreen(1660): <!>com.android.phone.InCallScreen 6486<!> onPhoneStateChanged: Activity not in foreground! Bailing out...
08-07 20:04:27.589: V/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1819<!> [DCT] onUpdateDataConnections: reason=2GVoiceCallStarted
08-07 20:04:27.589: V/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1819<!> [DCT] ---dc list---
08-07 20:04:27.599: V/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1819<!> [DCT] ---ds list---
08-07 20:04:27.599: V/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1819<!> [DCT] ds= SERVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT, enabled = false, active = v4:IDLE v6:IDLE
08-07 20:04:27.599: V/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1819<!> [DCT] ds= SERVICE_TYPE_MMS, enabled = false, active = v4:IDLE v6:IDLE
08-07 20:04:27.639: I/AudioService(1560): <!>android.media.AudioService 2658<!>  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@40769900
08-07 20:04:27.639: D/DrmServiceStart(11978): <!>com.lge.drmservice.DrmServiceStart 74<!> Network Connectiviy changed
08-07 20:04:27.689: D/DMClientService(14043): <!>com.lge.omadmclient.DmclientService 3088<!> updateNetworkState, networkType(0:Mobile, 1:WiFi): 0, networkState :DISCONNECTED
08-07 20:04:27.689: V/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1819<!> [DCT] ds= SERVICE_TYPE_SUPL, enabled = false, active = v4:IDLE v6:IDLE
08-07 20:04:27.689: V/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1819<!> [DCT] ds= SERVICE_TYPE_DUN, enabled = false, active = v4:IDLE v6:IDLE
08-07 20:04:27.699: V/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1819<!> [DCT] ds= SERVICE_TYPE_HIPRI, enabled = false, active = v4:IDLE v6:IDLE
08-07 20:04:27.699: I/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1823<!> [DCT] isReadyForData = true
08-07 20:04:27.699: I/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1823<!> [DCT] getRadioTechnology = RADIO_TECH_EDGE
08-07 20:04:27.699: I/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1823<!> [DCT] dataRegState = 0
08-07 20:04:27.699: I/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1823<!> [DCT] isReadyForData1 = true
08-07 20:04:27.699: I/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1823<!> [DCT] isReadyForData2 = true
08-07 20:04:27.699: I/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1823<!> [DCT] r.isGsm() isReadyForData = true
08-07 20:04:27.699: I/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1823<!> [DCT] Final isReadyForData = true
08-07 20:04:27.699: I/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1823<!> [DCT] Ready for data : 
08-07 20:04:27.699: I/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1823<!> [DCT]    getDesiredPowerState() = true
08-07 20:04:27.699: I/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1823<!> [DCT]    mCm.getRadioState() = RADIO_ON
08-07 20:04:27.709: I/DATA(1660): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1823<!> [DCT]    [DataRadioTech = RADIO_TECH_EDGE, data network state = 0, mMasterDataEnabled = true, is Roaming = false, dataOnRoamingEnable = false, isPsRestricted = false, desiredPowerState  = true, mSIMRecords = true/40445, cdmaSubSource = 1/, mRuimRecords = ]
08-07 20:04:27.759: V/DBController:UpdateRecord(14118): <!>com.tycoon.db.controller.DBController 2398<!> Number Records Updated = 1
08-07 20:04:27.989: E/Tethering(1560): <!>com.android.server.connectivity.Tethering 272<!> active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
08-07 20:04:27.989: D/CallNotifier(1660): <!>com.android.phone.CallNotifier 2421<!> - showing incoming call (custom ring query complete)...
08-07 20:04:27.989: D/CallNotifier(1660): <!>com.android.phone.CallNotifier 2421<!> showIncomingCall()...
08-07 20:04:27.989: D/WifiService(1560): BroadcastReceiver : android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
08-07 20:04:27.989: D/WifiService(1560): ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED pluggedType: 2
08-07 20:04:27.999: D/CallNotifier(1660): <!>com.android.phone.CallNotifier 2421<!> - updating notification from showIncomingCall()...
08-07 20:04:28.019: D/StatusBarService(1635): Notification has fullScreenIntent; sending fullScreenIntent
08-07 20:04:28.019: I/ActivityManager(1560): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10840000 cmp=com.android.phone/.InCallScreen } from pid -1
08-07 20:04:28.049: V/DBController:InsertRecord(14118): <!>com.tycoon.db.controller.DBController 1522<!> Record Inserted at rowId = 2
```

Comment: What's the exception in the log? What are the relevant pieces of code? We can't do much with just the description.

Comment: Error Log posted i'm unble to debug it..